# Throttling does not work with domain type in WSO2 ESB 4.0.3

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

When I try to config throttling with domain type in WSO2 ESB 4.0.3 for services ECHO.
I tried to send the soap message from client to server via command line:

curl --data-binary @soaptest.xml -H 'Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8' "http://dc2nix2d11:8282/services/echo"

But I still get the result although I set access deny for the domain of client machine.
I try to do the same config throttling with IP type and it's work.

Maybe Throttling does not work with domain type in WSO2 ESB 4.0.3 ?

Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is an known issue. It's already fixed in next ESB release

Answer (score 0):

If you are using service hosting feature on WSO2 ESB you could alternatively use recently released WSO2 AS 5.1.0 which support for domain based throttling to host your services till the next ESB version get released.